# This expression has type string t but an expression was expected of type string

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml so this might be obvious to some of you but hopefully you'll be patient with me.

At the top of my code, I have these:

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix
```

Then I have the following code:

```
let call_api config ip add_on lang =
  let protocol = if config.use_ssl then "https" else "http" in
  let uri = Uri.of_string (protocol ^ "://api.example.com/v2/?key=" ^ config.api_key ^ "&ip=" ^ ip ^ "&package=" ^ config.api_package ^ "&addon=" ^ add_on ^ "&lang=" ^ lang) in
  
  Lwt_main.run begin
    Client.get uri >>= fun (resp, body) ->
    let code = resp |> Response.status |> Code.code_of_status in
    let json = body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string in
    printf "JSON: %s\n" (json);
   (code, json)
  end
```

Then I'm calling it from another function and getting the below:

```
456 |     printf "JSON: %s\n" (json);
                              ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string t
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

Not really sure what's wrong. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I want this function to return the HTTP code and the body in a tuple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `Cohttp_lwt_unix.Body.to_string` does not a return a string but a `string Lwt.t`, in other words a promise to return a string.

Since you don't have a string yet, you cannot print it. What you want to do is to print the string when the promise will be resolved — at an unknown point in the future.

This is why `Lwt` provides different way to bind the future result of a promise and compute on this future result.

In practice, you can either use the `lwt` ppx which provides a `let%lwt` binding operator:

```ml
let%lwt json = body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string in
Format.printf "%s" json; ...
```

the `>>=` binding operator

```ml
let json_promise = body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string in
json_promise >>= (fun json ->
  ...
)
```

or equivalently the `bind` function:

```ml
let json_promise = body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string in
Lwt.bind json_promise (fun json ->
  ...
)
```

Comment: Went with the binding operator because having trouble making the lwt ppx work. Now everything's working fine! Thanks!